# Cross Account access Role creation for AWS Account using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, roles, boto3

I want to create a AWS Cross account role using boto3. Created the role from Console. But not able to create using boto3. I have two different AWS Accounts. I want to access one account from other using Assume Role. For that i need to create a permission in Account 1 so that Account 2 can access the same. But, I need to perform all the functionality using boto3 only.I used this code -

```
    iam = boto3.client('iam',aws_access_key_id='XXXXX',aws_secret_access_key='YYYY')
    role = iam.create_role(RoleName=<Role Name>,AssumeRolePolicyDocument='{"Version" : "2012-10-17","Statement": [{"Effect": "Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::<Account ID to which permission is granted>:root"} ,"Action":["sts:AssumeRole" ]}]}')
    policy = iam.create_policy(PolicyName=<Policy Name>, PolicyDocument='{"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": [{"Effect": "Allow","Action": "*","Resource": "*"}]}')
    policy_arn =  policy['Policy']['Arn']
    iam.attach_role_policy(PolicyArn=<Policy arn>,RoleName=<Name of the role to which policy need to be attached>)
```

Can this code be more optimized, may be lesser calls

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To obtain a useful answer, you will need to provide more details. Please edit your question and add more information, such as what you've tried (including code samples) and what particular problem you are experiencing. Also, it is not clear what you mean by "create a AWS cross account role" -- could you please define this in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no optimizing required. code working fine.

Answer (score -1):

In order to assume a role of account A from account B, here is the procedure.

In account A create a role with the following trust relationship.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "Root arn of the account B"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Save the above json in one of the file. Then write a function to create a role using this above trust relationship.

```
import boto3
role_name = "Name of the role"
client = boto3.client('iam')
client.create_role(RoleName=role_name,
                   AssumeRolePolicyDocument=trust_relationship())

def trust_relationship(self, role_name):
    with open('json_file_name', 'r') as data_file:
            trust_relationship = json.load(data_file)
        return json.dumps(trust_relationship)
```

Now in account B, create a role with the following json document, to assume the role of account A.

Policy Document:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Any other required actions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now use this policy document to attach to the role in account B which then assumes the role of account A.